# SQL Server : read JSON with unescaped keys?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have some JSON with unescaped keys in the DB I'm working on, but it seems SQL server can't read it. Is there any way to do it?

Example:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{ "site": "test" }', '$.site')
```

properly outputs `test`

However, when I remove the quotes surrounding the `site` key:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{ site: "test" }', '$.site')
```

it fails to execute, with the following error:

```
Msg 13609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 's' is found at position 2.
```

I know that [according to the specs](http://www.json.org/), a key has to be surrounded by quotes to be valid, but other parsers (such as JSON.NET) manage to decode such strings just fine, thus my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some sort of pre-processing could help..

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX) = '{ "pippo": "pippo", site: "test" }'

DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(255) = 'site'

DECLARE @PATTERN VARCHAR(255) = '%[{ ,]'

;WITH
J AS (
    SELECT STUFF(@JSON, PATINDEX(@PATTERN + @PATH + ':%', @JSON) +1, LEN(@PATH), '"'+@PATH+'"') NEW_JSON, PATINDEX(@PATTERN + @PATH + ':%', @JSON) p
)
SELECT JSON_VALUE(NEW_JSON, '$.'+@PATH) PATH_VAL
FROM J
```

Output

```
PATH_VAL
test
```

You could also write a simple procedure to fix all keys in your JSON, just wrap this loop in a function or a procedure to update it

```
DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX) = '{    asite: "test", pippo: "site",   site: "test" , "ciccio":"isgood" }'
DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(255) = '[a-zA-Z]%'
DECLARE @PATTERN VARCHAR(255) = '%[{ ,]'    
DECLARE @P INT = 0, @L INT = 0
DECLARE @W VARCHAR(255) = ''

SET  @P = PATINDEX(@PATTERN + @PATH + ':%', @JSON)  

while @P>0 BEGIN

    SET @P = @P +1 
    SET @L = CHARINDEX(':', @json, @p) - @p
    SET @W = SUBSTRING(@JSON, @P, @L)
    SET @JSON = STUFF(@JSON, PATINDEX(@PATTERN + @W + ':%', @JSON) + 1, LEN(@W), '"' + @W + '"')
    SET @P = PATINDEX(@PATTERN + @PATH + ':%', @JSON)       
    SELECT @P, @JSON
END
```

Output:

```
NEW_JSON
{    "asite": "test", "pippo": "site",   "site": "test" , "ciccio":"isgood" }
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... and what I wanted to avoid :)

Comment: I know, but the input is wrong.. if you want to use JSON_VALUE, you need to make it good. with the above logic, you can write a procedure to fix your data when you need a value..

Comment: The thing is, since the entire input is bogus, all the keys are unescaped (the example I gave was simplified to show my issue). Therefore, your solution is a starting point, but doesn't solve my problem: decoding '{ site: "test", otherkey: "test2" }' doesn't work. I ended up performing a string replace on all possible keys to fix the input..

Comment: take a look to updated answer, you can fix them in sql

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad to have been of some help.